# Runtime error in Web Config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config-transform

I have a web application in IIS 7.5 developed under ASP.NET 4.0 and SQL server 2008 R2. Now I am doing the testing the application, it was worked fine upto 10 entries suddently one error occured after i click the final stage of the "Submit" button in the form (before the application working fine in login form !!!) .How to overcome this problem, please help me.[image: Web Config Error]

Comment: Have you tried modifying your web.config file as advised in the error page? If you do, you will get more information about the error.

Comment: I did as per advice (CustomErrors mode = "Off"), The problem is solved but afraid about the error message. Is it shown in client side or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You have an exception on you application, but you must turn to `CustomError="On"`, in order to visualize your exception message.

You can't visualize your error, because `CustomError="Off"`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: The link said if I change: Mode="Off" => "Specifies that custom errors are disabled. This allows display of detailed errors".So i have to change the mode to "Off" ?

Comment: When you set CustomError, you will have basic error, and not custom Error, so you print in your screen original message of error.  You can also definie RemoteOnly in order to print in local your message, but your client don't access in this message, but receive nice message who don't afraid